# Contrapositive - Convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the convergence of a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \geq0}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as for all $ \epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x|< \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

What is the contrapositive of this definitiion.

**My thought :** There exist $ \epsilon > 0$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ $|x_n-x| \geq \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Negate the hypothesis and conclusion (inverse), and the reverse them (converse), will give you contrapositive? Perhaps include an attempt of yours?

Comment: Contrapositive applies to an if/then statement. Can you reword the definition into such a statement?

Comment: @majmun You are right, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the contrapositive or the negation?  The contrapositive only makes sense if you explicitly formulate the definition into an if/then statement, as Alex says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ $\exists n\ge N$ such that $|x_n-x|\ge \epsilon.$

Comment: If I could give you my appreciation I will, thank you !!

Comment: You're welcome. Your words are enough. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

if exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ ..... then $\{x_n\}$ is not convergent.

can you fill in the gap?

Comment: Apparently the OP could not.

Comment: @hardmath yes. it's hard to ask people to do something by themselves if there are others happy to offer the entire thing on a pretty platter :)

Comment: Your effort was worthwhile.  The OP tried (see the edit, which I think came within a minute your Answer), and that guess at filling in the blank, while wrong, probably set the stage for a deeper understanding of what the actual process of taking the contrapositive entails.